# PDFBox reads PDF data with extra spaces

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, pdfbox, spaces

I am using PDFBox to read this [PDF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zy3dpxlekfwp29/Wrong%20spaces%20sample.pdf?dl=0) using Java:

```
PDDocument pdf = null;
try {
    pdf = PDDocument.load( new File( path ) );
    PDFTextStripper s = new PDFTextStripper();
    String text = s.getText( pdf );
    System.out.println( text );
    pdf.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have noticed that it prints the text from the PDF with extra spaces, like "Jeremy Bern stein" instead of "Jeremy Bernstein". If i copy the text manually from the PDF file using Adobe Reader or any similar PDF viewer the text is pasted fine with no spaces.

I have tried the options PDFTextStripper.setAverageCharTolerance(...) and PDFTextStripper.setSpacingTolerance(...) to fix this, but none has worked!

Any idea what might fix that?

Comment: Please tell what version you are using.

Comment: I am using PDFBox version 2.0.8

Comment: Please update to 2.0.14 and try again.

Comment: IMHO Adobe is wrong here. It is pretty obvious that there is a space. Try the DrawPrintTextLocations.java example from the source code download, and see the red boxes.

Comment: I can see that. It's strange though how Adobe Reader handles this!

Comment: Which version of Adobe Reader do you use? When I Copy&paste the first line from the shared file, I get "Mark: Yes, in fact Jeremy Bern stein, who worked for Cycling ’74 [maker of Max and", i.e. I get the space!

Comment: I use Adobe Acrobat Reader DC V2019.010.20098